# Type or namespace 'Droid' does not exist in Lottie.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, lottie

I'm using Xamarin.Forms with Android and iOS. Trying to make Lottie animation work, but the latest version of Lottie (2.5.4) that supports .NET Standard 2.0 is giving a build error in the Android project:

> The type or namespace name 'Droid' does not exist in the namespace 'Lottie.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Looking at the Lottie GitHub source shows the namespace and class to be there, so I'm not sure why my Android project cannot find the reference.

I've tried downgrading Lottie, but no luck so far. The earliest version that contains the reference (2.5.0) does not work with .NET Standard.

Ideas?

Comment: May be a stupid question of mine, but did you reference the library (the NuGet package) from your android project?

Comment: Yes, I added the NuGet package at the Solution level to all platform-specific projects as well as the PCL/Xamarin.Forms project.

Comment: I am going to try to add the package manually to the platform-specific projects and then add the package Xamarin.Forms after. Thanks for try to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out to be an issue with the Target Framework version for the Xamarin.Forms Android project.

The latest version of Visual Studio 2017 creates new Xamarin.Forms Android projects with Android 7.1 target framework.

Changing to Android 8.1 fixed the compiler issue that could not find the Lottie.Forms.Droid namespace.

[image: Android project settings]

Comment: In my case I had to change from 8.1 to 9.0 then update Lottie nuget package to 2.7.0